# Swiper add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm currently building a slider with [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/api). Now I want to add a class to the "new" visible slide and remove the same class from the old on.
I tried it with this. But it's not nearly working as aspected.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    centeredSlides: true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    loop: true,
    onSlideNextStart: function (slider) {
            $(".swiper-slide[data-swiper-slide-index]").addClass("slider-collapse");
            $(".swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active").removeClass("slider-collapse");
    }

});
```

Amongst others I'm really struggling with the slide duplicates.

Comment: Can you give some more detail about this: "But it's not nearly working as aspected"? What's not working? What is happening? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Just a guess, but are you sure that the next slide has the `.swiper-slide-active` class when onSlideNextStart is invoked? Usually those types of functions are preliminary to any behind-the-scenes work that the library does (i.e. adding/removing classes). If i'm right, I think you'll have to tap into the API to grab the next `.swiper-slide` element. Looks like maybe the `slider.realIndex` or `slider.previousIndex` properties may be of use to you?